# How to connect NordVPN On Google Colab?

Tags: vpn, google-colaboratory

I would like to connect NordVPN on google colab.

For the moment, when I use the command : `nordvpn connect us`
I have this error : Whoops! Connection failed. Please try again. If the problem persists, contact our customer support.

To reproduce the error, create a new notebook and run the following lines :

```
#install
!wget -qnc https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian/pool/main/nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb && dpkg -i nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb
!apt-get -qq update
!sudo apt-get -qq download nordvpn
!dpkg --unpack nordvpn*.deb
!rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/info/nordvpn*.postinst
!rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/info/nordvpn*.postrm
!rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/info/nordvpn*.prerm
!apt-get install -yf
!chmod ugo+w /var/lib/nordvpn/data/
!apt-get clean
!rm -rf /tmp/*
!rm -rf /var/tmp/*

!sudo service nordvpn start
!nordvpn login --u=your_username --p=your_password
!nordvpn connect us #The error happens at this point
```

I don't know how to overcome it right now. Any help is welcome, Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well Google Colabs dosen`t allow working over a VPN